# sulu product bundle add field in add on form

Tags: symfony, twig, sulu

I'm working on SuluProductBundle. In product add on add I want to add a checkbox (see image) Which will save in table pr_product_addons.

[image]

I will add one field in table is_similar. So how can I change in form. I want to override twig. But in sulu I don't think I can override js files.

> /var/www/html/cart/src/Sulu/Bundle/ProductBundle/Resources/views/Template/product.addons.html.twig

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="product-addons-form">
    <div id="product-addons-toolbar" class="m-bottom-30"></div>
    <div id="product-addons-list"></div>
</form>
```

How can I change in this form to add a checkbox?